# Can I debug assemblies referenced through a private NuGet package without updating said package?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, nuget

Right now I have an internal/private package that is referenced by a few different projects. I can debug the package by stepping into the calls to that package (I don't know how it works, it just does), but that's not the issue.

Whenever I want to make changes in the package, I need to rebuild, do some funk in package explorer, then update package manually in the projects that use it. That's just to *test* some changes.

**Is it possible to set up Visual Studio so I can avoid the whole nuget step when running locally?**

The code that goes into the assembly for the nuget package is in a different solution, but same folder in TFS. My directory hierarchy is like so, and I want App.csproj to be able to reference NugetPackage.csproj:

```
|-NuGetPackage
| |-NuGetPackage.sln
| |-NugetPackageProjectDir
| | |-NugetPackage.csproj
|-App
| |-App.sln
| |-AppProjectDir
| | |-App.csproj
```